# Qt Bluetooth with Linux

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth, dbus

I'm trying to setup a bluetooth server for one device with Qt and can't figure out how to use QDbus and bluez.

The device is going to send strings. The two are already paired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite generic, what is your problem exactly?

A very good resource to start understanding bluetooth protocol and its programming model in C is http://www.btessentials.com/ 
The original resource that has reorganised into the mentioned book is available online [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/) Once you will have a fair understanding of the basic you could seriously think to wrap everything with Qt :)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I figured out, that using WiFi was the way to go (especially because of lack of time...)